# Error when using npm vue-cli

Tags: javascript, npm, vue.js, javascript-framework, vue-cli

Windows 10

node v8.9.2

npm 5.5.1

installed vue-cli through the use of npm but entering 'npm run dev' resulted in an error.

this is error message

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! webpack-simple@1.0.0 dev: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --open --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the webpack-simple@1.0.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\hansol\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2017-12-08T04_14_50_859Z-debug.log
```

Comment: can you share what command you have fired so far , for installing vue-cli, then vue init and then cd your dir then other commands for better understanding

Answer (score 1):

It appears as though you havent installed the node modules / dependencies.

Please try and run a

```
npm install
```

And see if that works

Answer (score 1):

I used to face this problem when the port is busy.
So confirm the port you are opening for the dev server.
you can also change the port using a flag "--port 3000".